# Mongodb should search in a part of string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb full text search - I have a string "Vipul" in my database and I am searching "vip" but its not getting records related to search.

It is asking full text like "Vipul", and I want to create autocomplete functionality in mongodb like google or any search engine.
I am using nodejs on server side.

Please help me out from this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you create the indexes of all the fields you want to search of?

Comment: yes...already created. Bu if I search some part of string then it will not working. it has to full text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB and fulltext search part of the word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828312/mongodb-and-fulltext-search-part-of-the-word)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, like this:

> db.myCollection.find({"fieldName": /vip/})

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its searching in whole database with all paramters in each document so it will very time consuming.
Is there any way to regular expression use in mongodb full text search ?